# How do I apply_filters to my custom function that is executed by add_action?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom function in my parent theme that hooks into the Wordpress admin_head, doing stuff with allowed domains which I define in the function. This part works perfectly.

But, I want to be able to add additional allowed domains to that function from the child theme (in other words, without modifying the original function in the parent theme). I thought that apply_filters may be a good solution but it doesn't seem to pass the additional domains in. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

This demonstrates the issue I'm trying to resolve:

```php
function custom_function( $additional_domains ) { 
    $allowed_domains = array(
        'domain1.com',
        'domain2.com',
        'domain3.com',
    );

    if ( $additional_domains ) {
        array_push( $allowed_domains, $additional_domains );
    }

    print_r( $allowed_domains );
}
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_function');


function send_domains_to_custom_function( $domains ) {
    return $domains;
}
add_filter( 'custom_function', 'send_domains_to_custom_function', 10, 1 );


$add_these_domains = array(
    'domain4.com',
    'domain5.com',
);
apply_filters( 'custom_function', $add_these_domains );
```

This is the result of the previous code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => domain1.com
    [1] => domain2.com
    [2] => domain3.com
)
```

But this is the result I'm wanting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => domain1.com
    [1] => domain2.com
    [2] => domain3.com
    [3] => domain4.com
    [3] => domain5.com
)
```

### Update: Final full working solution

Thanks to @melvin, and to provide clarity for anyone else who may find this later, here's what I ended up with:

Parent theme function:

```
function custom_function( $additional_domains ) { 
    $allowed_domains = array(
        'domain1.com',
        'domain2.com',
        'domain3.com',
    );

    $additional_domains = apply_filters( 'add_to_allowed_domains', $additional_domains );

    if ( !empty($additional_domains) ) {
        $allowed_domains = array_merge( $allowed_domains, $additional_domains );
    }

    print_r( $allowed_domains );
}
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_function');
```

Child theme function & filter:

```
add_filter('add_to_allowed_domains','add_to_domains_fn');
function add_to_domains_fn($domains){
   $domains= array('domain4.com','domain5.com');
   return $domains;
}
```

The parent theme function still works with the original allowed domains defined within it. If the child theme includes add_to_domains_fn() and the filter, it adds the additional domains in as expected.

Comment: You need to add apply_filter hook inside the function in the theme function.

Comment: @melvin can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: Normally apply_filters would be inside the function definiton so as to manipulate a variable available inside the same function.Since you have your apply_filters outside the function definition, i don't think it will work

Comment: @melvin add_filter defines how many args it can take, while apply_filters is where you define those args. So if the apply_filters is within the main function, how do I pass the additional params to it from outside the function?

Comment: see the answer i posted. This is the exact requirement as you need

Comment: @melvin right, I see what you're saying

Comment: I have update in my answer you requirement. Please see those

Comment: Have you seen my update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following function from **store-front** theme of **wordpress**

```
function storefront_header_styles() {
    $is_header_image = get_header_image();
    $header_bg_image = '';

    if ( $is_header_image ) {
        $header_bg_image = 'url(' . esc_url( $is_header_image ) . ')';
    }

    $styles = array();

    if ( '' !== $header_bg_image ) {
        $styles['background-image'] = $header_bg_image;
    }

    $styles = apply_filters( 'storefront_header_styles', $styles );

    foreach ( $styles as $style => $value ) {
        echo esc_attr( $style . ': ' . $value . '; ' );
    }
}
```

Have you seen how apply_filters is applied inorder to use the variable `$styles`?

```
$styles = apply_filters( 'storefront_header_styles', $styles );
```

Either the theme should put a filter in the position or you should manually add an apply_filter to the theme.

**#UPDATE**

I don't really get what code is from theme function and child theme. Assuming i have understood correctly, you need something as follows

```
function custom_function( $additional_domains ) { 
    $allowed_domains = array(
        'domain1.com',
        'domain2.com',
        'domain3.com',
    );
    $allowed_domains = apply_filters( 'add_to_allowed_domains', $allowed_domains );
    if ( $additional_domains ) {
        array_push( $allowed_domains, $additional_domains );
    }

    print_r( $allowed_domains );
}
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_function');
```

After changing the function as the above, you can use

```
add_filter('add_to_allowed_domains','add_to_domains_fn');
function add_to_domains_fn($domains){
   $domains= array('domain4.com','domain5.com');
   return $domains;
}
```

**N.B :** Since the function in the parent theme doesn't have any filters there, adding apply_filters manually is not recommended. Because the changes get overridden on next theme update. So you can ask theme developer to add a filter there

Comment: Ah yes okay. This gets me past the hurdle I was trying to figure out. The parent theme is my theme so I can modify it no problem. My array_push was wrong too... so I eliminated the if( $additional_domains ) {...} and updated the apply filters line like this: $allowed_domains = array_merge( $allowed_domains, apply_filters( 'add_to_allowed_domains', $additional_domains ) ); That gives me the exact results I'm looking for. Thank you!!!!

Comment: @JeremyCaris Happy to hear that. Since it's your own parent theme nothing to worry. Can you accept it as an answer